# Group similar column results into 1 row - KQL - Azure

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I can't figure out how to turn this:

```
20.20.5.4   vuxml.freebsd.org   
20.20.5.20  vuxml.freebsd.org   
20.20.8.7   edgedl.me.gvt1.com  
20.20.8.7   dl.google.com   
20.20.8.7   redirector.gvt1.com 
20.20.32.8  armmf.adobe.com
```

into this:

```
20.20.5.4   vuxml.freebsd.org   
20.20.5.20  vuxml.freebsd.org   
20.20.8.7   edgedl.me.gvt1.com  
            dl.google.com   
            redirector.gvt1.com 
20.20.32.8  armmf.adobe.com
```

Essentially, I am trying to summarize the destinations per IP address (group similar IP addresses, instead of showing 20.20.8.7 3 times per each result)
I can't figure out what aggregation to pass to "summarize", any ideas or links to documentation would be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps the make_list aggregation or make_set aggregation function would be of use here.

Comment: @MYousefi make_set() is perfect, I do have similar destinations in my real data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using the `make_list()` aggregation function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction

```
datatable(ip_address:string, destination:string)
[
    '20.20.5.4',  'vuxml.freebsd.org',
    '20.20.5.20', 'vuxml.freebsd.org',   
    '20.20.8.7',  'edgedl.me.gvt1.com', 
    '20.20.8.7',  'dl.google.com',
    '20.20.8.7',  'redirector.gvt1.com',
    '20.20.32.8', 'armmf.adobe.com',
]
| summarize make_list(destination) by ip_address
```

| ip_address | list_destination |
| --- | --- |
| 20.20.5.4 | [ "vuxml.freebsd.org" ] |
| 20.20.5.20 | [ "vuxml.freebsd.org" ] |
| 20.20.8.7 | [ "edgedl.me.gvt1.com", "dl.google.com", "redirector.gvt1.com" ] |
| 20.20.32.8 | [ "armmf.adobe.com" ] |